# MoveIt Planning and Execution Fails

Tags: ros, moveit, move-group-interface, ikfast, kdl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am facing some issues with `MoveIt`. I have a 6 DOF robot and I have created the moveit_config package for it. I have also followed [this](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/pr2_tutorials/planning/src/doc/planning_scene_ros_api_tutorial.html) tutorial and I am able to add objects to the `planning_scene` and attach them to my robot as well.

However, I am facing problems with the planning and execution in MoveIt. I have followed the [Move Group Interface](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/pr2_tutorials/planning/src/doc/move_group_interface_tutorial.html) tutorial and I have made some nodes for `Joint Space Goals` and also `Pose Goals`. Here is a snippet of my node:

```
moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup group("arm");
moveit::planning_interface::PlanningSceneInterface planning_scene_interface; 

std::vector<double> j_values;
j_values.resize(6);
j_values[0] = 0.00;
j_values[1] = -0.80;
j_values[2] = 0.73;
j_values[3] = 0.00;
j_values[4] = 0.755;
j_values[5] = 0.00;
group.setJointValueTarget(j_values);

//Motion plan from current location to custom position
moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup::Plan my_plan;
bool success = group.plan(my_plan);
ROS_INFO("Visualizing Plan %s",success?"":"FAILED");
/* Sleep to give RViz time to visualize the plan. */
sleep(5.0);

moveit_msgs::MoveItErrorCodes error_codes;
if (success == true)
{
ROS_INFO("Planning To Move");
error_codes = group.move();
ROS_INFO("%d", error_codes.val);
}
```

I have used the `GUI sliders` of the `joint state publisher` and noted these joint values so I am certain that they are valid positions. The funny part is that sometimes the planning fails and sometimes, even if the planning succeeds and I am able to visualize the trajectory in `RViz`, the fake trajectory execution fails.

I have also seen this behaviour when I set `Pose Goals` and `Cartesian Path Plan`.

I have setup `MoveIt` without any controllers. I am using the `fake_arm_controller`. Could this have to do with anything?

Also I was reading about `KDL` and in some places, it is given that it works for >= 6 DOF arms but in the book `Mastering ROS for Robotics Programming` on page 404, it is mentioned that KDL works well for DOF > 6.

Which one holds true? Should I start looking into `IKFast`?

Thanks for your inputs!

**EDIT** :

This is what I get in the terminal from which I launch my node :

```
[ INFO] [1482329713.395102382]: Loading robot model 'mitsubishi_rv6sd'...
[ INFO] [1482329713.792179428]: Loading robot model 'mitsubishi_rv6sd'...
[ INFO] [1482329714.748339492]: Ready to take MoveGroup commands for group arm.
[ INFO] [1482329718.508234984]: Visualizing Plan 
[ INFO] [1482329723.508560155]: Planning To Move
[ INFO] [1482329728.544356683]: ABORTED: No motion plan found. No execution attempted.
[ INFO] [1482329728.544465716]: -1
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'class_loader::LibraryUnloadException'
  what():  Attempt to unload library that class_loader is unaware of.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

and this from the move_group terminal :

```
[ INFO] [1482329714.751108276]: Planning request received for MoveGroup action. Forwarding to planning pipeline.
[ INFO] [1482329714.784687548]: LBKPIECE1: Starting planning with 1 states already in datastructure
[ INFO] [1482329717.107128883]: LBKPIECE1: Created 184 (156 start + 28 goal) states in 169 cells (151 start (151 on boundary) + 18 goal (18 on boundary))
[ INFO] [1482329717.107195147]: Solution found in 2.333180 seconds
[ INFO] [1482329718.133562849]: SimpleSetup: Path simplification took 1.026287 seconds and changed from 30 to 25 states
[ INFO] [1482329723.509644220]: Combined planning and execution request received for MoveGroup action. Forwarding to planning and execution pipeline.
[ INFO] [1482329723.509803230]: Planning attempt 1 of at most 1
[ INFO] [1482329723.545069363]: LBKPIECE1: Starting planning with 1 states already in datastructure
[ INFO] [1482329728.542936085]: LBKPIECE1: Created 121 (35 start + 86 goal) states in 108 cells (33 start (33 on boundary) + 75 goal (75 on boundary))
[ INFO] [1482329728.542997085]: No solution found after 5.006173 seconds
[ INFO] [1482329728.543036308]: Unable to solve the planning problem
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250548/moveit-planning-and-execution-fails/) by [bhavyadoshi26](https://answers.ros.org/users/26692/bhavyadoshi26/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2016-12-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-21**:
You write that "fake trajectory execution fails". Can you tell us how you determine that? Does RViz / MoveIt give you an error, are warnings printed, something else?

**Comment by [bhavyadoshi26](https://answers.ros.org/users/26692/bhavyadoshi26/) on 2016-12-21**:
Yes I get them on my terminal. I will edit the question to include them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the output it just looks like the planner was unable to find a solution. `LBKPIECE` might not be a good planner for your problem. Have you tried others? Like `RRTConnect`?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bhavyadoshi26](https://answers.ros.org/users/26692/bhavyadoshi26/) on 2016-12-22**:
I tried planning with `RRTconnect` and it works. @gvdhoorn What could be the reason `LBKPIECE` didn't work?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-23**:
Without knowing (much) more, that's difficult to say. It could be that your planning problem is just not one that `LBKPIECE` is suited for, or that some circumstance is making things difficult for it. See also [ros-planning/moveit#197](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/197).

**Comment by [yyf](https://answers.ros.org/users/29997/yyf/) on 2017-10-14**:
Hello,I maybe meet the same problem,but I don't know how to change the planner from LBKPIECE to RRTConnect.Can you tell me the solution?Thanks!

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2017-10-15**:
There are multiple ways to do that.
SImplest: use kinetic, we changed the default by now.
ad-hoc fix: `move_group.setPlannerID("RRTConnectkConfigDefault")`
config fix: you can add it as the [default planner](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/637) for your config